# Change disk type from Microsoft Basic to Linux filesystem

Tags: filesystems, fdisk, gdisk

I'm not clear where this is coming from and although it seems cosmetic I would like to change my disk type from Microsoft Basic to Linux filesystem

```
    WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 50.0 GB, 50010783744 bytes, 97677312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5E29C82B-93C9-47D8-B99C-A8DD0C1A2970


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648     17188863      8G  Linux swap
 3     17188864     97675263   38.4G  Microsoft basic
```

Comment: Do you care to keep the data on the Microsoft basic partition?

Comment: Hello @Jaleks this is strictly a linux instance so no. My apologies for not seeing your comment earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for Linux that is entirely cosmetic.

The `Type` field is based on the partition type GUIDs in your GPT partition table, and [there is a lot of possible types.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)

Changing the partition type GUID using Linux `fdisk` should not change the contents of the partition in any way. But based on the `WARNING` message, your version of `fdisk` seems to be a bit old, so you might want to be careful and take backups of any critical data first.

Basically what you'd need to do is:

```
# fdisk /dev/sda
[...]
Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-3, default 3): 3
Hex code (type L to list all codes): L

<A long list is displayed...> 
<Find the correct short code matching the "Linux filesystem" type GUID>

Hex code (type L to list all codes: <type the short code here>
Command (m for help): w
```

Your version of `fdisk` may have some differences. This example was produced using:

```
# fdisk --version
fdisk from util-linux 2.29.2
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about - solutions that work on the first try! Thank you `#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648     17188863      8G  Linux swap
 3     17188864     97675263   38.4G  Linux filesystem

[root~]# fdisk -version
fdisk from util-linux 2.23.2`